# Why doesn't HTML/JAVASCRIPT recongize my set password?

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to make a login system with a set password but it only sees the first password that I set with javascript.

```
    <p id="loginuser" style="display: block">Username:

      <input type="text" name="text1">

    </p>

    <p id="loginpass" style="display: block">Password:

    <input type="password" name="dasnk2">`

    </p>
    <input id="login" style="display: block" type="button" value="Log In" name="Submit" onclick="javascript:validate(document.getElementsByName("text1")[0].value,"Harrison",document.getElementsByName("dasnk2")[0].value,"88888888a"); validate(document.getElementsByName("text1")[0].value,"Isaac",document.getElementsByName("dasnk2")[0].value,"Tewst"); validate(document.getElementsByName("text1")[0].value,"Adam",document.getElementsByName("dasnk2")[0].value,"faa222014"); validate(document.getElementsByName("text1")[0].value,"Kelvin",document.getElementsByName("dasnk2")[0].value,"six921six921"); validate(document.getElementsByName("text1")[0].value,"Alap",document.getElementsByName("dasnk2")[0].value,"99999999nine")" >
```

this is my function for validating to be a bit more clear. (editied)

```
    function validate(text1,dasnk2,text3,text4) {

      if (text1 === dasnk2 && text3 === text4) {
          var redirect = document.getElementById('redirect');
          var embed = document.getElementById("embed");

          redirect.style.display = "block";
          embed.style.display = "none";

          setTimeout(function() {
            embed.style.display = "block";
            redirect.style.display = "none";
            loginuser.style.display = "none";
            loginpass.style.display = "none";
            login.style.display = "none";
            header.style.display = "none";
          }, 5000);
      } else {
        var incorrect = document.getElementById('incorrect');
        incorrect.style.display = "block";
        setTimeout(function() {
            incorrect.style.display = "none";
          }, 2000);
    }
    }
```

Comment: Do yourself a favor and do not use inline event handlers. Your code is unreadable like that.

Comment: how do i not use inline event handlers? @epascarello

Comment: "It only sees the first password" What do you mean only the first?

Comment: @PM77-1 so i should not have like 5 on clicks?

Comment: [`Element.addEventListener()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener)

Comment: @epascarello the first set of password (test and test)

Comment: Yes only one onclick is called.... the others overwrites it....

Comment: i removed 1 onclick for the second set of password (test1 and test1) but it doesn't work

Comment: It needs to have just one onclick and there is no need for `javascript:` Not sure why you want multiple onclicks in the first place.

Comment: @Andreas - removed

Comment: @epascarello i deleted all the extra "onclick"s and "javascript:"s and it still doesn't work for the other passwords

Comment: no clue what that means....

Comment: You mean you are trying to have a list of passwords that are valid and you are checking to see if it matches one (I hope you know this is not secure, view source and you see the username and password...)

Comment: Yes i know that.

Answer (score 0):

You have multiple onlick events. Each one overwrites the previous one. So in the end the only onclick event that will be called is the last one. If you want to call multiple things inside an inline event handler you need to use semicolons.

```
onclick="function1(); function2(); function3();"
```

In your case validate is probably trying to cancel the submission event. You are not cancelling it since there is no return. So it would have to be

```
onclick="return function1() && function2() && function3();"
```

Ideally you would not be using inline event handlers, but you would bind the event with addEventListener.

```
document.getElementById("myForm").addEventListener("submit", function () {
  var valid1 = validate(...)
  var valid2 = validate(...)
  var valid3 = validate(...)

  return valid1 && valid2 && valid3;
});
```

Comment: the function validate is for to check if text1 === text2 && text3 === text4

Comment: what does the return do? (im a noob at this)